# Doubts in uploading image into file database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Focus on the questions, **please**

I have the following **HTML**

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="uploadProfilePicture();" method="post" name="prof_picture">
 <input id="upload_profile_picture" style="display:none;"name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
 <input id="upload_profile_picture2" value="Submit" type="submit" style="display:none;">
 <a id="change_profile_picture" class="profile_option" onclick="$('#upload_profile_picture').click();">Mudar foto de perfil</a>
```

**PHP** (profileFunctions.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['prof_picture'])){
    alert("test");
}
```

**JS**

```
function uploadProfilePicture(){

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: "profile/profileFunctions.php",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

}
```

I have used ajax before but the thing is I'm actually really in doubt because of this file being an image:

> 1º What exactly should be in "data:" within the ajax request? And what
>   should I do to parse the file correctly?
>
> 2º In PHP image validation how can I retrieve the extension of the
>   file AND how exactly should I do the isset($_POST)?
>
> 3º If I am to propose the image to the user instantly if ajax.success
>   should cache be set to true? How does cache behave on this situation?

Comment: Have you considered using a plugin like uploadify? http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I don't suggest putting the image data into the database. I would suggest saving it to the file system and storing its location into the database.

Comment: @JustinWood I never said I would :)

Comment: Name of the question suggests otherwise.

Comment: @JustinWood you were right, sorry

Answer (score 0):

XHR technology does not permit to upload the images.

You have to find a workaround, something like using an iframe.

Comment: are you sure about that? xD

Comment: @user111671 as far as I know. Similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: xhr2 does support images/files

Comment: @AdamMerrifield yea, but it's not XHR

Comment: @Daveel I'm suggesting it because he isn't specifying a browser & http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Comment: @AdamMerrifield hmmm, I actually thought cross-browsiness of XHR2 was worse than what it is today

Comment: @Daveel it is quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Please use iframe instead of ajax.

```
<form target="my_iframe_name" action="my_script_can_receive_file.php" ....>
...
</form>
<iframe name="my_iframe_name"  onload="javascript:alert('uploaded')" style="width:1px;height:1px;position:absoulte;left:-99999px;top:-99999px" src="javascript:void(0)"></iframe>
```

However, if you want check the status of your upload, you may need more work on both [my_script_can_receive_file.php] and [js] to talk the status to the main frame.

Comment: But use iframe ->how<- exactly? I've always thought iframe was supposed to embed something and ajax to connect in real time with the server isn't that right? Then why would I use iframe?

Comment: AJAX does not support file transfer. iframe is an adapter, you post into the iframe instead to current frame (the main page) by using [target] and [action] attributes in [form] tag. Then, you use [onload]  in [iframe] to find out the status of you upload result